# Silence Detection in AMR

Tags: algorithm, audio, artificial-intelligence, voice-recognition, amr

How to make difference between silence and other audio in AMR?
I want to implement custom Voice Activity Detection mechanism. Any ideas on how to proceed? 
I need the algorithm for that.

Comment: See Wikipedia [entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_activity_detection) on VAD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to PCMU codec and 0 there is detected as silence.